# Performance of array of struct types

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, struct

Example:

```
// Potentially large struct.
struct Foo
{ 
   public int A;
   public int B;
   // etc.
}

Foo[] arr = new Foo[100];
```

If Foo is a 100 byte structure, how many bytes will be copied in memory during execution of the following statement:

`int x = arr[0].A`

That is, is arr[0] evaluated to some temporary variable (a 100 byte copy of an instance of Foo), followed by the copying of .A into variable x (a 4 byte copy).

Or is some combination of the compiler, JITer and CLR able to optimise this statement such that the 4 bytes of `A` are copied directly into `x`.

If an optimisation is performed, does it still hold when the items are held in a `List<Foo>` or when an array is passed as an `IList<Foo>` or an `ArraySegment<Foo>`?

Comment: Maybe your confusion will be gone if you realize that Array itself is a class (not struct).

Comment: I have clarified the question, it is regarding the memory access bandwidth of arr[0].A

Comment: The question is still confusing. `arr[0].A` is a *variable*. That variable consumes four bytes; it's an integer variable, so what else could it consume? I don't know what this thing called "memory access" that you are referring to is. Are you asking how many bytes are read when you read from a four byte variable? Four. How many bytes are written when you write to a four-byte variable? Four.

Comment: OK so my Q is: are there circumstances where arr[0] is evaluated first causing a 100 byte read, followed by .A, a further 4 byte read. E.g. consider ArraySegment<Foo>.

Comment: @EricLippert To me the question makes sense though. Because although both are called indexers, `array[0].A` and `list[0].A` have very different behavior for `struct`s, don't you agree?

Comment: @IvanStoev: `list[0].A` is not a variable; is that the difference you mean? If that's the OP's question then they should more clearly *ask that question*. A code sample that clearly shows what operations they're interested in would help.

Comment: @EricLippert I guess the question is for me :) Indeed, that's what I meant - for any other indexer property (prior C#7.0 of course) except the `Array`, `[0].A` will cause copy the whole struct and then access the member.

Comment: @EricLippert  I think part of the issue here is that I wasn't aware of the deficiencies in my Q until I read the various criticisms of it; from which I have learned and attempted to improve/clarify the Q. I.e. my 'discussion and discovery' approach of using this site is at odds with how you're expecting the site to be used. In any case, I thank you for your answer as it did mostly cover my intended Q.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm intrigued by your mention of C#7.0; is there a behaviour change in version 7?

Comment: @redcalx C# 7.0 added ref returns, which would let you write a custom object that could return a variable, rather than a value.

Comment: @redcalx The behavior is the same. What I had in mind was that with the new [ref locals and returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#ref-locals-and-returns) feature one can make own collection types with the same indexer semantics as the arrays, which was not possible before. But I'm afraid standard BCL collections/interfaces will not utilize that possibility due to backward compatibility policy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Value types are *copied by value* -- hence the name. So then we must consider at what times a copy must be made of a value.  This comes down to analyzing correctly when a particular entity refers to a *variable*, or a *value*. If it refers to a value then *that value was copied from somewhere*. If it refers to a variable then its just a variable, and can be treated like any other variable.

Suppose we have

```
struct Foo { public int A; public int B; }
```

Ignore for the moment the design flaws here; public fields are a bad code smell, as are mutable structs.

If you say

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

what happens?  The spec says:

- A new eight byte variable `f` is created.
- A temporary eight byte storage location `temp` is created.
- `temp` is filled in with eight bytes of zeros.
- `temp` is copied to `f`.

But that is not what actually happens; the compiler and runtime are smart enough to notice that there is no observable difference between the required workflow and the workflow "create `f` and fill it with zeros", so that happens. This is a *copy elision optimization*.

**EXERCISE: devise a program in which the compiler cannot copy-elide, and the output makes it clear that the compiler does not perform a copy elision when initializing a variable of struct type.**

Now if you say

```
f.A = 123;
```

then `f` is evaluated to produce a variable -- not a value -- and then from that `A` is evaluated to produce a variable, and four bytes are written to that variable.

If you say

```
int x = f.A;
```

then f is evaluated as a variable, `A` is evaluated as a variable, and the value of `A` is written to `x`.

If you say

```
Foo[] fs = new Foo[1];
```

then variable `fs` is allocated, the array is allocated and initialized with zeros, and the reference to the array is copied to `fs`. When you say

```
fs[0].A = 123;
```

Same as before. `f[0]` is evaluated as a *variable*, so `A` is a *variable*, so 123 is copied to that variable.

When you say

```
int x = fs[0].A;
```

same as before: we evaluate `fs[0]` as a variable, fetch from that variable the value of `A`, and copy it.

But if you say

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
list.Add(new Foo());
list[0].A = 123;
```

then you will get a compiler error, because `list[0]` is a *value*, not a *variable*. You can't change it.

If you say

```
int x = list[0].A;
```

then `list[0]` is evaluated *as a value* -- a copy of the value stored in the list is made -- and then a copy of `A` is made in `x`.  So there is an extra copy here.

**EXERCISE: Write a program that illustrates that `list[0]` is a copy of the value stored in the list.**

It is for this reason that you should (1) not make big structs, and (2) make them immutable. Structs get copied by value, which can be expensive, and values are not variables, so it is hard to mutate them.

> What makes array indexer return a variable but list indexer not? Is array treated in a special way?

Yes. Arrays are *very special types* that are built deeply into the runtime and have been since version 1.

The key feature here is that an array indexer logically produces an *alias to the variable* contained in the array; that alias can then be used as the variable itself.

All other indexers are actually pairs of get/set methods, where the get returns a value, not a variable.

> Can I create my own class to behave the same as array in this regard

Before C# 7, not in C#. You could do it in IL, but of course then C# wouldn't know what to do with the returned alias.

C# 7 adds the ability for methods to return aliases to variables: `ref` returns.  Remember, `ref` (and `out`) *parameters* take variables as their operands and cause the callee to have an alias to that variable. C# 7 adds the ability to do this to *locals* and *returns* as well.

Comment: What makes array indexer return a variable but list indexer not? Is array treated in a special way? Can I create my own class to behave the same as array in this regard?

Comment: And is an array accessed via a ref of type IList<Foo> also yield a variable?

Comment: @redcalx Write up the code and try to compile it to find out.

Comment: @Servy I am doing, but I would also like to have a full understanding of the intent and design to distinguish between what is guaranteed to happen, and what may be the consequence of an optional optimisation. I think Eric's answer mostly covers it though.

Comment: @redcalx If a variable is returned, then the code works if you try to write to it, if a variable *isn't* returned, then the code can't compile.  There's no optional optimizations at play.  Either it lets you write to it or it doesn't.  Optimizations can only improve speed without changing functionality, not change behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The entire struct is *already* in memory. When you access `arr[0].A`, you aren't copying anything, and no new memory is needed. You're looking up an object reference (that might be on the call stack, but a struct might be wrapped by a reference type on the heap, too) for the location of `arr[0]`, adjusting for the offset for the `A` property, and then accessing only that integer. There will not be a need to read the full struct just to get A.

Neither `List<Foo>` or `ArraySegment<Foo>` really changes anything important here so far.

However, if you were to pass `arr[0]` to a function or assign it to a new variable, that would result in copying the `Foo` object. This is one difference between a struct (value type) and a class (reference type) in .Net; a class would only copy the reference, and `List<Foo>` and `ArraySegment<Foo>` are both reference types.

In .Net, especially as a newcomer the platform, you should strongly prefer `class` over `struct` most of the time, and it's not just about the copying the full object vs copying the reference. There are some other subtle semantic differences that even I admittedly don't fully understand. Just remember that class > struct until you have a good empirical reason to change your mind.

Comment: Hi, I've clarified the question.

Comment: And I've clarified the answer.

Comment: "Neither List<Foo> or ArraySegment<Foo> really changes anything important here so far." - my reading of Eric's answer is that he's saying that this is not the case; care to comment? (I would be interested in your interpretation/view of his answer).

Comment: No, they are the same, because in his words you're still working with variables rather than values.

Comment: Hmm, the compiler disagrees. `arr[0].A = 123` compiles because `arr[0]` is a variable, whereas list[0] is not a variable, it yields a value, i.e. a copy of the element at [0].  Thus changing that copy would not change the value in the list, hence the compiler detects it as having no effect and thus flags it as an error. This is also the case for an array pointed to be a ref of type IList<Foo> or an ArraySegment<Foo>

Comment: I think you'll find `list[0].A = 123` does change the value in the list, and if it's not compiling take a closer look at the compiler error.

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't compile, for the reasons Eric described. "Cannot modify the return value of 'List<Foo>.this[int]' because it is not a variable"